# Iteratively improving lower bound for $\phi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, totient-function

This question came up while looking at the well known lower bound for $\phi(n)$, the Euler Totient function

$$
\phi(n) \gt {n \over {e^\gamma \ln \ln n} + {3 \over \ln \ln n}} \tag{1}
$$

For $m$ such that $gcd(m, n) = 1$, we have

$$
\phi(mn) = \phi(m) \phi(n) \tag{2}
$$

If we take $m = p_k\#$, the $k$-th primorial and $\gcd(p_k\#, n) = 1$, we have

$$
\phi(p_k\#) \phi(n) \gt {{p_k\# \times n} \over {e^\gamma \ln \ln (p_k\# \times n)} + {3 \over \ln \ln (p_k\# \times n)}} \tag{3}
$$

Therefore,

$$
\phi(n) \gt {p_k\# \over \phi(p_k\#)} \times {n \over {e^\gamma \ln \ln (p_k\# \times n)} + {3 \over \ln \ln (p_k\# \times n)}} \tag{4}
$$

I tried $n = 61997851 = 7919 \times 7829$ as an example. $\phi(n) = 7918 \times 7828 = 61982104$ using the standard formula.

The known lower bound formula gives us $\phi(n) \gt 3578918$ which is quite far off. I then estimate $\phi(n)$ using the various primorial values. The table of the estimated $\phi(n)$ for various values of $k$ is given below:

| $k$ for $k$-th primorial | $\phi(n)$ estimate |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 44494923 |
| 50 | 59431412 |
| 100 | 60063451 |
| 110 | 60106645 |
| 150 | 60279934 |
| 195 | 60398410 |
| 197 | 60402559 |
| 199 | 60406310 |
| 200 | 60408296 |

I used WolframAlpha to do the calculations. [Here is the link to an example for $p_{110}\#$ on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%20y%20%3D%20%28a*n%29%20%2F%20%28EulerPhi%5Ba%5D*%28%28e%5Egamma%20ln%20ln%20%28a*n%29%29%20%2B%203%2F%28ln%20ln%20%28a*n%29%29%29%29%2C%20n%20%3D%2061997851%2C%20a%20%3D%20primorial%28110%29%20over%20the%20reals&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22gamma%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22NamedConstant%22%7D).

[image: Example calculation for p_110#]

The question I have is:
Is there a way we can ensure that the lower bounds for $\phi(n)$ evaluate to a sharper bound upon successive iterations using the above method or combining with an upper bound formula? (such as $\phi(n) \le n - \sqrt{n}$ for composite $n$).

For instance, in the same example, if we used the upper bound formula, we get:

$$\phi(n) \le 61989978$$

**Can we then find the range for $k$ that satisfies the inequality and then search for the factor of $n$ within that range?**

$$
n - \sqrt{n} \ge \phi(n) \gt {p_k\# \over \phi(p_k\#)} \times {n \over {e^\gamma \ln \ln (p_k\# \times n)} + {3 \over \ln \ln (p_k\# \times n)}} \tag{5}
$$

EDIT: An earlier version of this question had an incorrect computation of $\phi(n)$ which spawned an inquiry into a different issue. The current question is focused on approaches for improving the bounds with other iterative techniques.

Comment: I think the issue. may be the multiplicative formula $\phi(mn) = \phi(m) \phi(n)$ holds true only if $gcd(m, n) = 1$. Clearly, $gcd(p_k\#, n) \ne 1$ when $p | p_k\#$ and $p | n$.. But even $p_{200}\#$ does not share a common factor with $n$ in the given example. So, it must be something else.

Comment: $\phi(61997851)=61982104$. You probably made an inadvertent typo: $7918\times 7628=60398504$, but it should be $7918\times 7828$

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks @nickgard. Good catch. That seems to be the issue. I'll edit the question for correctness. So, the iterative procedure does bring the estimate closer to the actual value of $\phi(n)$. That makes sense.

Comment: I think one would have to make "upon successive iterations using the above method or combining with an upper bound formula" more precise for this question to be answerable.